# I need help implement a Javascript code into the PHP file

Tags: php, javascript, html

I need help implementing a Javascript code into my PHP file that would replace the default search box with a new one. Do I have to use echo? How would it look like?
Thanks in advance or your help, I've been trying for hours now.

```
$(function () {
    $('a[href="#search"]').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#search').addClass('open');
        $('#search > form > input[type="search"]').focus();
    });

    $('#search, #search button.close').on('click keyup', function(event) {
        if (event.target == this || event.target.className == 'close' || event.keyCode == 27) {
            $(this).removeClass('open');
        }
    });
```

Implement to this PHP:

```
<?php
//Header File
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<?php
wp_head();
?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="global" class="global">
    <div class="pagesidebar">
        <div class="sidebarcontent">    
            <h2 id="sidelogo">
                <a href="<?php echo vibe_site_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php  echo apply_filters('wplms_logo_url',VIBE_URL.'/assets/images/logo.png','pagesidebar'); ?>" alt="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>" /></a>
            </h2>
            <?php
                $args = apply_filters('wplms-mobile-menu',array(
                    'theme_location'  => 'mobile-menu',
                    'container'       => '',
                    'menu_class'      => 'sidemenu',
                    'fallback_cb'     => 'vibe_set_menu',
                ));

                wp_nav_menu( $args );
            ?>
        </div>
        <a class="sidebarclose"><span></span></a>
    </div>  
    <div class="pusher">
        <?php
            $fix=vibe_get_option('header_fix');
        ?>
        <header class="sleek transparent <?php if(isset($fix) && $fix){echo 'fix';} ?>">
            <div class="<?php echo vibe_get_container(); ?>">
                <div id="searchdiv">
                    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
                        <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
                            <input type="text" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php _e('Hit enter to search...','vibe'); ?>" />
                            <?php 
                                $course_search=vibe_get_option('course_search');
                                if(isset($course_search) && $course_search)
                                    echo '<input type="hidden" value="course" name="post_type" />';
                            ?>
                            <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <?php

                            if(is_home()){
                                echo '<h1 id="logo">';
                            }else{
                                echo '<h2 id="logo">';
                            }
                        ?>

                            <a href="<?php echo vibe_site_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php  echo apply_filters('wplms_logo_url',VIBE_URL.'/assets/images/logo.png','header'); ?>" alt="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>" /></a>
                        <?php
                            if(is_home()){
                                echo '</h1>';
                            }else{
                                echo '</h2>';
                            }


                            $args = apply_filters('wplms-main-menu',array(
                                 'theme_location'  => 'main-menu',
                                 'container'       => 'nav',
                                 'menu_class'      => 'menu',
                                 'walker'          => new vibe_walker,
                                 'fallback_cb'     => 'vibe_set_menu'
                             ));

                        ?>


                        <?php
                            if ( function_exists('bp_loggedin_user_link') && is_user_logged_in() ) :
                                ?>
                                <ul class="topmenu">
                                    <li><a href="<?php bp_loggedin_user_link(); ?>" class="smallimg vbplogin"><?php $n=vbp_current_user_notification_count(); echo ((isset($n) && $n)?'<em></em>':''); bp_loggedin_user_avatar( 'type=full' ); ?><span><?php bp_loggedin_user_fullname(); ?></span></a></li>
                                    <?php do_action('wplms_header_top_login'); ?>
                                    <?php
                                    if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) || (function_exists('is_plugin_active_for_network') && is_plugin_active_for_network( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php'))) { global $woocommerce;
                                    ?>
                                    <li><a class="smallimg vbpcart"><span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"><?php echo (($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count)?'<em>'.$woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count.'</em>':''); ?></span></a>
                                    <div class="woocart"><?php woocommerce_mini_cart(); ?></div>
                                    <div id="searchicon"><i class="icon-search-2"></i></div>                            
                                    </li>
                                    <?php
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </ul>
<?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?>
                            <?php
                            else :
                                ?>
                                <ul class="topmenu">
                                    <li><a href="#login" class="smallimg vbplogin"><span><?php _e('LOGIN','vibe'); ?></span></a></li>
                                    <?php
                                    if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) || (function_exists('is_plugin_active_for_network') && is_plugin_active_for_network( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php'))) { global $woocommerce;
                                    ?>
                                    <li><a class="smallimg vbpcart"><span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"><?php echo (($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count)?'<em>'.$woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count.'</em>':''); ?></span></a>
                                    <div class="woocart"><?php woocommerce_mini_cart(); ?></div>
                                    <div id="searchicon"><i class="icon-search-2"></i></div>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </ul>
<?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?>    
                            <?php
                            endif;
                        ?>
                        <?php
                            $style = vibe_get_login_style();
                            if(empty($style)){
                                $style='default_login';
                            }
                        ?>
                        <div id="vibe_bp_login" class="<?php echo $style; ?>">
                        <?php
                            vibe_include_template("login/$style.php");
                        ?>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <a id="trigger">
                        <span class="lines"></span>
                    </a>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that all `JS` is inside the `<script>` tags and you can use `PHP` anywhere as long as it's `.php` file and it's inside the `<?php` and `?>`. Simple as that!

It's kind of ugly and it's far from super readable but that's the way to do it.

---

```
<?php
$php_code = 'My PHP is here!!';

/*Close PHP*/ ?>

<script> //All JS inside the <script> tags

    var jsCode = 'All my JavaScript here!!';

    <?php
    if( $i_can_also_use_php_here ) { ?>

        var jsAgain = 'Just JS and PHP back and forth!!'; <?php 

    } ?> // "}" is closing PHP if statement

</script> 

<?php //Open PHP, no more JS, <script> tag is closed

$continue_php = 'Let's continue this beast!!'; ?>
```